# Not able to create a NET Core 1.1 project when using the command DotNet New

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I tried to create a new ASP.NET Core 1.1 project using:

```
dotnet new
```

However I got the following error:

```
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.0.1' was not found.
Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
The following versions are installed: 1.1.0
Alternatively, install the framework version '1.0.1'.
```

But I do want to create a 1.1 project. I have the following installed:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: You are likely using dotnet from 1.0.1 sdk and not from 1.1.0 sdk. You can use `where.exe dotnet` to see which one you are using. If you are using the old one you will need to update your %PATH% to include the 1.1.0 sdk folder or use the full path to the dotnet from new sdk.

Comment: Process of elimination, please uninstall the old version of .net sdk.

Comment: What does `dotnet --info` shows you?

Comment: Yes, I solved it by uninstalling the old version of the SDK, Preview 2.1, and updated the Preview 3 to Preview 4. Now I am able to create Projects With Csproj files

Comment: @MiguelMoura I had this same issue too because I installed a 1.1 preview.  The problem related to a known issue where the preview used the wrong Core version folder name: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/1.1/1.1-known-issues.md  After I renamed the folder like the issue states, it worked.